# cannot instantiate abstract class & no overloaded function could convert all argument types (c2259 & c2665)

Tags: visual-c++, c++17, sfml

I'm working in visual studio and I keep getting these error.
E0322   object of abstract class type "GameState" is not allowed
Error   C2259   'GameState': cannot instantiate abstract class
Error   C2665   'GameState::GameState': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types

I understand that I need to override the functions from the state class in the gamestate class and I thought that I did that but apparently not. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

code:

state.h:

```
class State { 
private:    
sf::RenderWindow* window;   
std::vector<sf::Texture> textures; 
public:     
State(sf::RenderWindow* window);    
virtual ~State();       //this means that all child classes must define these
virtual void endState() = 0;    
virtual void update(const float& dt) = 0;   
virtual void render(sf::RenderTarget* target = nullptr) = 0; };
```

state.cpp

```
#include "State.h"

State::State(sf::RenderWindow* window)
{
this->State::~State(){}
```

gamestate.h

```
#include "State.h"
class GameState :
public State
{
private:

public:
GameState(sf::RenderWindow\* window);
virtual \~GameState();
void endState();
void update(const float& dt);
void render(sf::RenderTarget\* target);
};
```

Gamestate.cpp

```
#include "GameState.h"

GameState::GameState(sf::RenderWindow\* window)
: State(window){}
GameState::\~GameState(){}

void GameState::endState(){}

void GameState::update(const float& dt){}

void GameState::render(sf::RenderTarget* target = nullptr){}
```

game.h

```
#include "GameState.h"
class Game
{
//variables
sf::RenderWindow* window;
sf::Event sfEvent;

sf::Clock dtClock; //frame tracker
float dt; //deltatime

std::stack<State*> states;

//initialization
void initWindow();
void initStates();

public:
Game();
virtual \~Game();

void updateDeltaTime();
void updateSFMLEvents();
void update();
void render();
void run();

};
```

game.cpp

```
//I will be leaving out all the unnecessary code to save space
#include "Game.h" 
void Game::initStates() {
 this->states.push(new GameState(this->window)); //this is where the problem is
}
```

hovering over GameState says that State::endState()/render()/update() has no override

please help!!!

Comment: Your code does not compile because of other errors, maybe you should fix that first.  Hint: the default parameter value should be with the fuinction declaration (in the .h) and not with its implementation (in .cpp), using the keyword override would also help you find any errors in the declaration of your derived class.